# Converting space separated integers to lists in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

```
[['label1', 'label2']
  ['1 2 3', '1 2 3']
  ['4 5 6', '4 5 7']]
```

So each column is considered as strings. I would like to apply a l2 distance between each element of the two labels so I need to convert the columns to list of float.

Is there a "clean" way to do that, better than a double for loop with something like `[float(x) for x in element.split()]` ?
(My dataframe is huge so I would like something quite optimized)

Comment: Have you tried `pd.to_numeric()` ? http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.19.2/generated/pandas.to_numeric.html I don't know about the performance but it does what you want

Comment: I tried but I cannot manage to apply it.. always got error message ! I I do `pd.to_numeric(my_df)` I get a `TypeError` and if I do `pd.to_numeric(my_df.label1)` I get `ValueError`

Comment: `pd.to_numeric()`works only on Series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply `str.join`, join both columns, then split again using `str.split`. Finally, convert to float using `df.astype`.

```
df

  label1 label2
0  1 2 3  1 2 3
1  4 5 6  4 5 7

df = df.apply(' '.join).str.split(expand=True).astype(float).T
df

   label1  label2
0     1.0     1.0
1     2.0     2.0
2     3.0     3.0
3     4.0     4.0
4     5.0     5.0
5     6.0     7.0
```

---

Based on your comments, use `applymap` (slow)

```
from functools import partial
f = partial(lambda x: [float(y) for y in  x.split()])

df = df.applymap(f)
df

            label1           label2
0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
1  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 7.0]
```

To apply this to only some columns, use

```
c = ['label1', 'label2'] # add any other columns, if you want 
df[c] = df[c].applymap(f)
```

Note that by retaining your columns as lists, you lose out on all of `pandas` vectorisation benefits.

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear in my question : I want to do the distance between each row : `dist([1 2 3], [1 2 3]) = 0` and `dist([4 5 6], [4 5 7]) != 0`. So I need to keep each rows, but just convert the type from string to a list of float

Comment: @Arcyno Is this what you're looking for? Note that keeping columns of lists is very slow.

Comment: Yes it looks great. Let me test it !

Comment: @Arcyno Minor speed gain using `functools.partial`

Comment: Is there a way to apply it only to some columns ? (I actually have some columns, say `'label3'` that I would like to keep as string)

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda x: [float(y) for y in x.split()])
print (df)
            label1           label2
0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]
1  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 7.0]
```

Another solution:

```
a = [[list(map(float, x.split())) for x in df[v].values.tolist()] for v in df.columns]
print (a)
[[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]], [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 7.0]]]

df = pd.DataFrame(a)
print (df)
                 0                1
0  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]
1  [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]  [4.0, 5.0, 7.0]
```

Comment: Ahhhh it's my answer, please remove it :P

Comment: Sorry, I have first this, and it is difference with partial... :(

Comment: I could have argued with you, but I deleted my answer :)